# TreeView as vertical menu - how to get name of associated MenuItem

Tags: treeview, menuitem, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am working on changing `TMainMenu` to `TTreeView` i.e.vertical menu.
I am able to create the `TTreeView` and by calling `AddChildObject()` I have `Node.Data`.

I was able to call the `OnClick` event of an associated `MenuItem` using `TMenuItem(TreeView1.Selected.Data).Click`.

How to get the name of the associated MenuItem?

I tried
`TMenuItem(TreeView.Selected.Data).Name`, but the `Name` shows as an empty string.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.TreeViewClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned ((Sender as TTreeView).Selected) then 
  begin
    TMenuItem ((Sender as TTreeView).Selected.Data).Click;
    // this works fine i.e. on node click specific menuitem click is called
    
    TMenuItem ((Sender as TTreeView).Selected.Data).Name;
    // Name is empty inspite of menuitem name being not empty
  end;
end;
```

Code for populating the TreeView:

```pascal
procedure CopyMenuToTreeView( aMenu: TMenu; aTreeview: TTreeView );
  procedure AddItems( anItem: TMenuItem; aParentNode: TTreeNode );
  var
    node: TTreeNode;
    i: Integer;
    begin
      for i := 0 To anItem.Count -1 do begin
      node := aTreeView.Items.AddChildObject(
        aParentNode,
        anItem.Items[i].Caption );
      AddItems( anItem.Items[i], node );
    end;
  end;
begin
  Assert( Assigned( aTreeView ), 'No treeview' );
  aTreeView.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    aTreeView.Items.Clear;
    if Assigned( aMenu ) then
      AddItems( aMenu.Items, nil );
    aTreeView.FullExpand;
  finally
    aTreeView.Items.EndUpdate;
  end; { Finally }
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CopyMenuToTreeview( MainMenu1, TreeView1 );
end;
```

Also, here is the existing `TMenuItem.OnClick`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.MI_Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Common code for many menuitem
  //Code for creating form based on name of menuitem
  CreateMIForm('Frm'+((Sender as TMenuItem). Name));
end;
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question and add the relevant code you already wrote preferably in a simple basic program reproducing the difficulty you have.

Comment: You added a TMenuItem to each node, right? You created at run time, right? And you forgot to give it a name, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I have created ttreeview at runtime with each menuitem as node in treeview. I have assigned onClick event to it and calling the associated menuitem click.

Comment: And you forgot to give a name to each one... No name means TMenuItem(Treeview.selected.data).name is empty. Please check that. And PLEASE edit your question to add the code you have so far.Link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65183058/edit

Comment: Actually there is already TMainMenu which isdesign time component and it has menuitems with name.I will add the code

Comment: I have edited my question. Also I cannot find node.name property

Comment: OK, you edited, but there is nothing I can quickly check. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The problem is that if you have a bad question, it will be soon closed by moderators. You have to follow the rules!

Comment: @Seli you didn't show the code that populates the TreeView with nodes

Comment: @Remi thanks for editing.. I have added the treeview code.

Comment: You code doesn't compile. AddChildObject lacks an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code - `AddChildObject()` needs a 3rd argument. In `TreeView1Click` I used an intermediate variable.

Tested with Delphi 10.4.1.

```pascal
unit TreeViewMenuDemoMain;
    
interface
    
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ComCtrls;
    
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    File1: TMenuItem;
    Close1: TMenuItem;
    Exit1: TMenuItem;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Close1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Exit1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;
    
var
  Form1: TForm1;
    
implementation
    
{$R *.dfm}
    
procedure CopyMenuToTreeView( aMenu: TMenu; aTreeView: TTreeView );
  procedure AddItems( anItem: TMenuItem; aParentNode: TTreeNode );
  var
    node: TTreeNode;
    i: Integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 To anItem.Count -1 do begin
      node := aTreeView.Items.AddChildObject(
        aParentNode,
        anItem.Items[i].Caption,
        anItem.Items[i]);
      AddItems( anItem.Items[i], node );
    end;
  end;
begin
  Assert( Assigned( aTreeView ), 'No treeview' );
  aTreeView.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    aTreeView.Items.Clear;
    if Assigned( aMenu ) then
      AddItems( aMenu.Items, nil );
    aTreeView.FullExpand;
  finally
    aTreeView.Items.EndUpdate;
  end; { Finally }
end;
    
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CopyMenuToTreeView(MainMenu1, TreeView1);
end;
    
procedure TForm1.Close1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('File/Close');
end;
    
procedure TForm1.Exit1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('File/Exit');
end;
    
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MenuItem : TMenuItem;
begin
  if Assigned ((Sender as TTreeView).Selected) then begin
    MenuItem := TMenuItem((Sender as TTreeView).Selected.Data);
    MenuItem.Click;
    // this works fine i.e. on node click specific menuitem click is called
    
    ShowMessage(MenuItem.Name);
  end;
end;
    
end.
```

DFM file:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object TreeView1: TTreeView
    Left = 16
    Top = 24
    Width = 205
    Height = 257
    Indent = 19
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = TreeView1Click
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 280
    Top = 36
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 364
    Top = 124
    object File1: TMenuItem
      Caption = '&File'
      object Close1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Close'
        OnClick = Close1Click
      end
      object Exit1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Exit'
        OnClick = Exit1Click
      end
    end
  end
end
```